# Clustering- FileLockClusterService usage

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm trying to use Camel Clustering using a File lock (active/standby nodes) approach. Based on the documentation (https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/clustering.html) it appears that in spring boot configuration file we can define the cluster details as below. The problem I have is, I don’t know which maven dependency I need to add in order to configure the below properties.

```
camel.component.file.cluster.service.enabled = true
camel.component.file.cluster.service.id = ${random.uuid}
camel.component.file.cluster.service.root = ${java.io.tmpdir}
```

My IDE is not able to recognize any such property.
[image]

pom.xml

```
....
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-master-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-file-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
 
....
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
....
```

Spring-boot version: 2.2.5.RELEASE

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: looks like there is a an issue in the camel-file-starter which I'll fix, however, the properties are listed in the file-component documentation page: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html

Comment: it has already been fixed on master so it will be available next release

Comment: okay, Got it. Thank you for the information.